# Connect ImageButton to edge of screen in drawable background 

Tags: android, xml, layout, button

Trying to get the top left white space to touch the edge of the screen but can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I don't want the green showing on the left, I want the white covering it up.

[image]

BUTTON CODE:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/itempicture"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@drawable/profilepicture" />
```

DRAWABLE/PROFILEPCTURE_DEFAULT CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item><shape>
            <gradient android:type="linear" android:angle="270" android:startColor="#FFFFFF" android:centerColor="#FFFFFF" android:endColor="#424242" />

            <stroke android:width="0dp"></stroke>

            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="35dp" />

            <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem I had to change the padding from the LinearLayout holding the object by adding `android:paddingLeft="0dp"` to LinearLayout xml code in the main. This is different then changing the padding within the drawable which was the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Padding in the left side, try remove that.

Comment: The padding keeps the image/text inside the button away from the left side of the edge of the button, not the button from the screen. I already tried that solution earlier. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

In your DRAWABLE/PROFILEPCTURE_DEFAULT CODE:

You have the line 
padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp".

This puts internal spacing on all sides of your object.

Remove to android:left="5dp" to get rid of the spacing on the left.

Comment: The padding within the drawable keeps the image/text inside the button away from the left side of the edge of the button, not the button from the screen. I already tried that solution earlier. Thanks for helping.